# Querying the Stripe API for all charges per customer?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to query the Stripe API for all charges for a specific customer or do we need to retrieve all charges, and then filter them for the customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the docs, the [Charges API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/list) at `https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges` takes a `customer` optional argument.